# Which is the first filed country of patent CN 203733449 U?

Tags: international, cn203733449u

If an inventor wants patent protection in more than one country than he has to file a patent application in different countries separately for the same invention. So the country in which the applicant has filed the first application is called First Filed Country.

What is the first filed country of [CN 203733449 U](http://www.google.com/patents/CN203733449U)?

Comment: Please provide the patent number you are asking about.

Answer (score -1):

The first (and only) country where this was filed is China.

Edit with more details:

Consider this page: https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?II=0&ND=3&adjacent=true&locale=en_EP&FT=D&date=20140723&CC=CN&NR=203733449U&KC=U

The Priority number of this Chinese Utility Model is identical to its Application number; ergo, there is no claim to priority from any other application in China or elsewhere, and so China is indeed the first filed country.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you described how you made this determination.

Comment: Thank you Eric for the suggestion. There are many ways of coming to this conclusion, for example, according to this page:
https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?CC=CN&NR=203733449U&KC=U&FT=D&ND=&date=20140723&DB=&locale=

The Priority number of this Chinese Utility Model is identical to its Application number; ergo, there is no claim to priority, and so China is indeed the first filed country.

Comment: Comments aren’t permanent so it is best for you to edit your answer. In my opinion, the best answers both literally answer the question and also teach how the answer was determined. It’s good to have you contributing.